uniswap v3 Calculate entrance price of a liqidity pool
for example I have added a liquidity on a uniswap v3 pool with this data:
pair: CAKE-ETH
min price: 1,074.54
max price: 1,118.39
cake amount: 116.752
eth amount: 0.077786
tick spacing: 200

now how can I calculate entrance price in this pool?
